# Ruleset not in Decision Services list of Rule Execution Server console for Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

I deployed a ruleset to the Business Rules service on Bluemix. I confirmed that it was deployed in the Decision Services tab.

However, when I navigate to the Rule Execution Server console > Explorer > Transparent Decision Service Information, I do not see my ruleset listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I executed the ruleset, the corresponding decision service was listed under Explorer > Transparent Decision Service information.
This is because the ruleset does not exist as a decision service until it has been executed.